# In python, I want to sort a dictionary based on the dictionary of dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

In python I have a dictionary of dictionary such as

```
my_dict = {A:{mark1:15, mark2:12, mark3:20}, B:{mark1:10, mark2:90, 
mark3:14},C:{mark1:11, mark2:19, mark3:25}}
```

I want to print the dictionary sorted based on the mark3 of each one, for example I want to print in this format ( I just dont know how to sorted based on mark3?)

```
C : {mark1:11, mark2:19, mark3:25}
A : {mark1:15, mark2:12, mark3:20}
B : {mark1:10, mark2:90, mark3:14}
```

Thanks

Comment: _In general_, you cannot print a dictionary sorted, because (again, _in general_) Python dictionaries cannot be sorted. However, you can sort dictionary items (keys and values), sort them, and then print each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom key for sorting:

```
print(dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['mark3'], reverse=True)))
```

This outputs (in Python 3.6+):

```
{'C': {'mark1': '11', 'mark2': '19', 'mark3': '25'}, 'A': {'mark1': '15', 'mark2': '12', 'mark3': '20'}, 'B': {'mark1': '10', 'mark2': '90', 'mark3': '14'}}
```

Prior to Python 3.6 dicts are unordered, so you should use `collections.OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_dict = OrderedDict([('A', {'mark1': '15', 'mark2': '12', 'mark3': '20'}), ('B', {'mark1': '10', 'mark2': '90', 'mark3': '14'}), ('C', {'mark1': '11', 'mark2': '19', 'mark3': '25'})])
print(OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['mark3'], reverse=True)))
```

If you want to make `mark2` a secondary key, you can make the key a tuple instead:

```
print(dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1]['mark3'], x[1]['mark2']), reverse=True)))
```

Comment: Thanks , solved my issue. is there any way that if mark3 is the same then sorted by mark2 ? for example if :       

    my_dict = {A:{mark1:15, mark2:12, mark3:20}, B:{mark1:10, mark2:90, 
    mark3:20},C:{mark1:11, mark2:19, mark3:25}}

then print 
    C : {mark1:11, mark2:19, mark3:25}
    B : {mark1:10, mark2:90, mark3:20}
    A : {mark1:15, mark2:12, mark3:20}

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer with a solution to make `mark2` a secondary key.